# Converting to spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, spherical-coordinates

I have the triple integral: $${\int_{-1}^1} {\int_{-\sqrt {1-x^2}}^{\sqrt {1-x^2}}} {\int_{- \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}^1}   dzdydx$$

I want to evaluate this integral by changing to spherical coordinates.

I'm relatively new to spherical coordinates but I have a basic idea of the overall process I'm supposed to use.

I need to find values for $\rho$, $\theta$, and $r$ using the bounds of the integral I currently have.

I tried setting $z = -\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}$ which then means $z^2 = -x^2 -y^2$ but I'm not sure how to obtain $\rho$ from this.

I also tried $z=1$ but I'm not sure how to represent $z$ in spherical coordinates so that I can find $r$

The last one I tried is $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and got $x^2 +y^2 =1$ but again, I'm not sure how to represent this in spherical coordinates.

I am able to do the actual integration once I have a triple integral with spherical coordinates set up, my issue is converting to spherical coordinates.

Overall I think my main issue is that I don't know any of the general conversions I should know in order to be able to answer this question, such as what $z$ is in spherical coordinates or what $x^2 +y^2$ is in spherical coordinates. If someone could show me how to convert to spherical coordinates it would help a lot.

(Also if anyone knows a website (or can be bothered to list them) where all the transformations I will need are listed please link it so I can try to learn these transformations so I can do these questions myself)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it have to be spherical coordinates? Cylindrical seem more appropriate in this case

Comment: Are these the main 3 conversions I'll be using in questions like this?  Also, I'm just looking through the solution to this question (The working out isn't given only some steps and the answer are provided) and I'm not sure how $x^2 + y^2$ becomes $r^2 sin^2{\rho}$, did they just use the transformations you've given, expand and then simplify? Or is there some other transformation they used?

Comment: @Andrei In this question they ask for both cylindrical and spherical but I've practiced cylindrical a bit so I'm ok with this, spherical is new to me and I wasn't aware of the transformations I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ \displaystyle {\int_{-1}^1} {\int_{-\sqrt {1-x^2}}^{\sqrt {1-x^2}}} {\int_{- \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}^1} \ dz \ dy \ dx$

Note the region is bound by the following surfaces:

Cone $z = - \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, cylinder $x^2+y^2 = 1$ and plane $z = 1$.

$x = \rho \cos\theta \sin\phi, y = \rho \sin\theta \sin\phi, z = \rho \cos\phi$

If we are integrating wrt $\rho$ first, we have to split the integral into two -

i) when $\rho$ is bound by the cylinder

$x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \implies \rho \leq \csc\phi$

Using $z = - \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, upper bound of $\phi = \cfrac{3\pi}{4}$

Lower bound of $\phi$ is at the intersection of cylinder and plane $z = 1$.

$z = 1 \implies \rho = \sec \phi$

So at intersection, $\sec\phi = \csc\phi \implies \phi = \cfrac{\pi}{4}$

ii) when $\rho$ is bound by the plane $z = 1$

$\rho \leq \sec\phi, 0 \leq \phi \leq \cfrac{\pi}{4}$

So integral is,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{\pi/4}^{3 \pi/4} \int_0^{\csc\phi} \rho^2 \sin \phi \ d\rho \ d\phi \ d\theta \ $ +

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \int_0^{\sec\phi} \rho^2 \sin \phi \ d\rho \ d\phi \ d\theta$

Comment: This is great thanks, but could I please ask how you got the value of $\phi$ from $z=-\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}$? Also, how did you get $\phi$ when you had $1/{cos{\phi}} = 1/{sin{\phi}}$?

Comment: $x^2+y^2 = \rho^2 \sin^2\phi, \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \rho \sin\phi$, $z = \rho \cos\phi$, So when $z = - \sqrt{x^2+y^2}, \tan\phi = - 1$ and we know in spherical coordinates, $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi$. At what $\phi, \tan \phi = - 1$?

Comment: Ah ok, Just another quick question, $x^2 +y^2 = {\rho}^2 sin^2 \phi$, did you get this by subbing in the transformations for $x$ and $y$, expanding, then simplifying, or is it just a general transformation I should know?

Comment: it's better to remember that but you can easily get by plugging in $x, y$ too. Also if you are working with spherical coordinates, you should know that $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ cone is also called $\phi = \pi/4$ cone. Just helps.

Comment: Ok, perfect, thank you so much for the quick response and the help

Comment: Oh wait, sorry, could you quickly explain how you found the intersection of the plane and the cylinder?

Comment: I understand everything else

Comment: At intersection of cylinder and plane, $\rho = \sec \phi = \csc \phi$, right? That leads to $\tan\phi = 1 \implies \phi = \pi/4$